# Python: Outputting data from a function called in a function

Tags: python, function, output

I have a function called from within a function like this:

```
def counter(number):
  number = number + 1
  return number

def iterator(iteration, function):
  for i in range(iteration):
    mfunction = function
    output = mfunction()
  return output
```

I want to call it something like this:

```
number = 0
number = iterator(5, partial(counter, number))
print number
```

This returns 1, where as it should return 5, because the count function should have been called 5 times.
I realize that somehow the data isn't outputting correctly but I can't figure out how to return out of the for loop.

This question may seem redundant, because I could easily do something like:

```
for i in range(5):
  number = counter(number)
```

But the latter example defeats the purpose of this program.

I think the problem is that I need to create an argument in the counter function to account for the iterator function. But the problem in my actual program is that I would have to modify many functions to do this, and I am trying to avoid that.

I am not that familiar with calling functions inside of functions and any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: `number = number + 1` in `counter` function does change only the parameter `number`, not the `number` outside the function.

Comment: `partial(counter, number)` is equivalent to `partial(counter, 0)`. So the code is calling `counter(0)` 5 times.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't know how to get that number out

Comment: well it prints as 1, so the number is affected. It just doesn't repeat in the for loop.

Comment: It is affected by `number = iterator(..)`. (After the iterator function return = all 5 iteration is done. not after individual call of `counter`)

Comment: Add `print 'counter is called with', number` in the first line of the `counter` function. And you will see what I mean.

Comment: Yes I understand. But the function I used partial for has varying numbers of arguments and without partial it takes 'exactly 3'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`partial(counter, number)` is equivalent to `partial(counter, 0)`. So the code is calling `counter(0)` 5 times.

```
def counter(number):
    number = number + 1
    return number

def iterator(iteration, function, arg):
    for i in range(iteration):
        arg = function(arg)
    return arg

number = 0
number = iterator(5, counter, number)
print number # => 5
```

---

```
def counter(number, delta):
    number = number + delta
    return number

def iterator(iteration, function, *args):
    args = list(args)
    for i in range(iteration):
        ret = function(*args)
        args[0] = ret
    return ret

number = 0
number = iterator(5, counter, number, 5)
print number # => 25
```

Comment: This works but the number of arguments is variable which is why I used partial.

Comment: @NickSimas, Are the number of arguments and the number of return value's items always equal?

Comment: The return is always 1 value. The arguments vary.

Comment: @NickSimas, You can use [Arbitrary Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). Or you can pass a tuple or a list and use [Unpacking Argument list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Comment: @NickSimas, But that doesn't make sense. `counter` receives the return value of itself as parameter.

Comment: could you give me an example with * operator?

Comment: @NickSimas, I added an example.